# How can I get access to an ng-repeat $index variable in my JSTL code?

Tags: html, angularjs, jsp, jstl, el

I have a div block that uses an ng-repeat.  Within this angular loop, I need to have a  loop in JSTL, but for this inner loop I will need the current index of the angular loop.

So imagine that this is the basic structure:

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in fooBarCtrl.blah | orderBy: '_order' track by $index">
    <c:forEach var="element" items="${JSTLarray[**NEED_ANGULAR_INDEX_HERE**]}">
        <c:out value="foobar" />
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Due to the way angular and JSPs operate, I'm not sure it's even possible to gain direct access to the $index variable in my JSTL code.  However, I am trying to think of some other solution to this problem.

How do I get the current index of the angular loop inside of my JSTL/EL parent loop?

Comment: JSTL is rendered on the server side and Angular is a javascript framework running on the client...   I think it might be quiet a challenge to access the javascript variables on the client side. You probably could do it with a partitial rendering on the server side as in JSF.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off serializing your JSTLArray to JSON and passing it via `ng-init` somehow, and leave the iterating to `ng-repeat` rather than a `c:forEach`. It's hard to mix these two worlds because one is server side rendering and one is client side rendering, so obviously you wouldn't have access to `$index` in JSTL because that only gets evaluated after the page has been compiled and sent down to the client.

The way I've got around this limitation in the past is to have a custom JSTL function such as `${lib:toJSON(JSTLArray)}` which will convert said array to JSON (or any Java bean) via the Jackson library. In this way, now you can render the contents of the array however you want using Angular. Then, I would create an "init" function in my Angular controller, and pass that JSON in and do whatever with it. The init call would look something like `ng-init="fooBarCtrl.someInitFunction(${lib:toJSON(JSTLArray)})"`.

Here is a snippet of code for the `toJson` method I wrote previously.

`

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomFunctions {

    /**
     * Serializes a Java object to a Json string.
     *
     * @param object
     * @return
     */
    public static String toJson(Object object) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "{}";
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

`

Hope this helped.